# Cant count GROUP BY correctly

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

SQL:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM bb_posts post
LEFT JOIN bb_topics topic
  ON topic.topic_id = post.topic_id
LEFT JOIN bb_forums forum
  ON forum.forum_id = topic.forum_id
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups_groupmeta group_meta
  ON topic.forum_id = group_meta.meta_value
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups `group`
  ON group_meta.group_id = `group`.id
LEFT JOIN wp_bp_groups `parent`
  ON `group`.parent_id = `parent`.id
WHERE group_meta.meta_key = 'forum_id' &&
  (topic_title LIKE '%searchterm%' ||
  MATCH(post.post_text) AGAINST('searchterm')) &&
  topic_status = 0
GROUP BY post.topic_id;
```

Returns a count of all posts for each topic. I want to find a count for all the topics. I know i could do a count() in php with the returned rows, but I want a SQL solution instead.

ie

```
2
2
4
11
3
3
2
```

instead of the total of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a total count, just remove `GROUP BY post.topic_id`

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You can do it by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
([your original query here])a
```

Comment: that will show the total count for posts. I want the total count for topics.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a single line returned which sums the values of all the lines currently returned, correct?

If so, remove the group by from your query.